# Porqué el intercepto de una ecuación lineal es tan diferentes entre R y excel?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regresión-lineal

Tengo dos cuestiones. La primera de ellas relacionada con los valores de la ecuación de regresión lineal que obtengo en R y excel. Tengo exactamente los mismos datos en los dos programas y obtengo los siguientes valores de la ecuación en cada programa:

```
excel--> y=-92.83+4.48x

R-->y=-9020+4.48x
```

y al ver las gráficas de cada programa, me parece más lógico el intercepto de excel, ya que en R no existe tal punto (-9020).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que tuviera que dividir el intercepto de R entre 100 para tener algo semejante a excel. Tienen alguna idea del porqué?

y la segunda cuestión es relacionada con la ecuación de regresión. Existe alguna manera "automática" para integrarla en el gráfico, como lo hace Excel? O simplemente debo correr mi modelo lineal, anotar los valores de los parámetros y luego programarlo dentro de mi código de ggplot?

Los datos son (En cualquier caso, el año 9999 y el 2018 se corresponden, son los mismos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código que usé para hacer el gráfico y ajustar el modelo es:

hem<-ggplot(df, aes(x=año, y=VGmedio))+
  geom_point(color="purple")+
  geom_line(color="purple")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1990,2018,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-100,60,15))+
  #theme_light()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  geom_smooth(se=TRUE, method="lm")

kk<-lm(VGmedio ~ año, data=hemodel)

Comment: Por favor comparte los datos con los que has generado ambas gráficas y el código en R. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Caro, que es el 9999 luego de 2017 en el gráfico de Excel? Estás segura que son exactamente los mismos valores? 
El intercept de Excel es cuando año vale 1990, mientras que R lo debe estar calculando para cuando año (variable X) vale 0.
Los predichos de ambos modelos, son iguales? 
Adhiero al comentario de @PatricioMoracho

Comment: @P.Paccioretti 9999 y 2018 tienen los mismos años, sólo que para poder graficar en R o que quería tuve que modificarlo. He mirado los residuos en R pero tengo problemas en chequear los de Excel......... Sigo intentando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que se están usando criterios distintos para el modelo lineal. La ecuación de la recta que te da R: `-9020 + 4.48x`, lo que básicamente te estaría diciendo es que cuando el año sea `0` el valor de `y` será `-9020`. En cambio Excel, intuyo, está considerando los años como valores ordinales de 1 a 29 (año 1990 a 9999). Si realmente estuviera tomando los valores como variables continuas el gráfico sería totalmente distinto por el espacio de valores que hay entre 2017 y 9999. El Excel entonces te  da un valor del `intercept` que resulta lógicamente visible en el gráfico, el año 1999 es `x=1` y el valor de `y` es `-73,88` de modo que cuando `x` sea 0 es razonable ver que `y` sea `92.837`. En R, al considerar los años como una variable continua, el año 0 obviamente se fue de la escala.

Si quieres que R reproduzca lo mismo que estarías haciendo con el Excel, puedes numerar los años:

```
df$n_año <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Hacemos el modelo, pero usando `n_año`:

```
modelo <- lm(VGmedio ~ n_año, data = df)
coef(modelo)
(Intercept)       n_año 
 -92.839187    4.488567 

summary(modelo)$r.squared
[1] 0.9707258
```

Y ahora sí, podemos observar que los valores son similares a los del Excel. Y para graficar y agregar la ecuación de la recta, puedes partir del modelo ya construido, extraer los coeficientes y construir la etiqueta a incorporar al gráfico:

```
a = format(as.numeric(coef(modelo)[1]), digits = 4)
b = format(as.numeric(coef(modelo)[2]), digits = 4)
r2 = format(summary(modelo)$r.squared, digits = 4)

paste0("y = ",
      a,
      ifelse(as.numeric(coef(modelo)[2]) >= 0, "+", "-"),
      b,
      "x",
      "\n",
      "R² = ",
      r2
) -> eqtext

ggplot(df, aes(x=n_año, y=VGmedio)) + 
  geom_point(color="purple") + 
  geom_line(color="purple") +
  geom_smooth(se=TRUE, method="lm") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$n_año, labels=seq(1990,2018,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-100,60,15)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  geom_text(x = 10, y = 40, label = eqtext,   check_overlap = TRUE ) +
  labs(x="Años")
```

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una vez más, muchísimas gracias por tu explicación.